# How can I manipulate an injected class in my junit test to return a specific value?

Tags: junit, easymock

I am a complete novice when to it comes to junit/mocking objects and need some guidance.

My class under test includes a calculator to determine the number of jobs to kick off. I was getting a Null Pointer Exception when attempting to set expectations on a mock of the calculator, so I inject it into the class under test via a setter in my setUp method.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
classUnderTest.setCalculator(mockCalc);
```

In my test, I call the expected method on my mockCalc with some mocked data as follows:

```
List<Job> myConcurrentJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

myConcurrentJobs = Arrays.asList(mockWorkflowJob);
jobs = Arrays.asList(mockWorkflowJob);
result = Arrays.asList(mockWorkflowJob);
```

The actual call to the method is here:

```
EasyMock.expect(mockcalc.calculateJobs(jobs, myConcurrentJobs,mockDS)).andReturn(1);
```

When I run the method, the value returned is zero, which negates my test. This could very well be expected as the mocked lists are not suitable for the logic of the calculateJobs method but the relationship between mocked life and real life is still unclear to me. I've tried to place break points in the calculateJobs method to pinpoint if/where things are going bad but they are not being hit in Eclipse which may or may not be due to the injection. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of calculateJobs() method. Is it int (or other primitive type) ? How any mock framework works is, when you expect a method with certain param, and if while running the test, nothing match is found from what you expected, it **returns the default value of return type**. E.g. if your return type is int, it will return 0, if its String/Object, it will return null.

When you are expecting a method with argument, the arguments at the time of expect and which is actually called, must be **EQUALS**.From Equals, i mean, it will use the equals method to compare the equality of the values. So if you pass a string "SOMETHING" and expected "SOMETHING".

In you method, you are passing 3 argument, i.e. jobs, myConcurrentJobs,mockDS. Make sure what you are expecting and what is actually called satifies the "EQUALS" criteria then only 1 will be return, otherwise default value of return type will be return, which is 0 (assuming you have int return type)

Please share the whole Test and actual code, will be able to help exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Irathod. Turns out I had not instantiated the Calc object prior to running the test. Once instantiated, I set my inputs to return a desired int and it is now working.